# make a soap response show a list of custom objects with xsd file

Tags: java, xml, maven, soap, xsd

So i created my own SOAP service using Spring Maven Java. I am able to create a custom object "Machine" which displays the hostname and the ip address of the machine. Because there are multiple machines my goal is to show the list of machines instead of showing only 1 machine.

My xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://company.be/cloudtool/backendProofOfConcept"
targetNamespace="http://company.be/cloudtool/backendProofOfConcept"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="getDevicesRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <!-- This one isn't used -->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="getDevicesResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="machine" type="tns:machine" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element> -->

<xs:complexType name="machine">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="hostname" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="primaryip" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

When i test this using soapUI i get the following output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKPXd.png

but i want it to show the hostname and ip for each machine in a list. I found the following [list example](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_list.asp) but this only seems to work with simple types like int or string and not for a custom types like my machine type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I assume this should work:

```
<xs:element name="getDevicesResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="machine" type="tns:machine" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: When i use: minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
the setMachine function from the class getDevicesResponse isn't generated. so i'm unable to set multiple machines

Comment: You should have a list then. You probably have to call something like `getMachines().add(mashinexy);` to add to it. Maybe add the generated class to your question.